# Spring Boot Configuration Processor, Duplicate @ConfigurationProperties definition for prefix

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

In a Spring Boot application, I want to use `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation with the same prefix to configure my two data sources depending to the profile. Why is it forbidden by Spring Boot Configuration Processor ? The error reported by gradle is:

```
...
:compileJava ... error: Duplicate `@ConfigurationProperties` definition for prefix 'spring.datasource'
```

Notes:

- "Run As->Spring Boot App" works in STS
- Without spring-boot-configuration-processor dependency, gradle build works (but the warning `When using @ConfigurationProperties it is recommended to add 'spring-boot-configuration-processor' to your classpath to generate configuration metadata` appears)

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases" }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:1.5.4.RELEASE'
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password = sa
```

hello.Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setAdditionalProfiles("prod");
        app.run();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("dev")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSourceDev() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url(generateDevUrl())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("prod")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSourceProd() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .url(generateProdUrl())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those beans are exactly the same why would you even needs that configuration?!

Comment: My production code is more complicated. I have simplified it too much. I just updated my sample code.

Comment: Nonetheless still looks like you are doing things you shouldn't be doing. Why do you need this? The main issue, imho, is that you have different methods to generate a URL. But that is something you shouldn't have in code but in config.

Comment: I'm having same issue.. this kind of setup works using intelij but as soon as I tried to compile with gradle it throws an error. "error: Duplicate ..."  do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused on how this works. The code should mostly stay the same. The properties change when you define which profile to load at start up.

**application-dev.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.url=
```

**appilication-prod.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.url=
```

And only one bean setup the datasource.

Comment: OK for the data source, it was not a good example. My question is more general: I want to create multiple beans that have some commons properties defined in `application.properties`, some profile specifics properties defined in `application-<profile>.properties` and some "runtime properties" that must be programmed. I want to use `@ConfigurationProperties` to handle commons and profile specifics properties (to avoid having multiple `@Value` tags and `setProp()`in my `@Configuration` class.